# Where is "vfbasics.pdb" on windows 7?

Tags: windbg

It seems to be absent from the MS public symbol store, but it is also absent from the C:\Windows\System32 folder.

My symbol path is configured correctly, because I do get symbols for kernel32.dll and alike downloaded from the MS public symbol store and recognized by windbg.

Comment: that pdb is installed as part of application verifier, did it install vfbasics.dll in c:\windows\system32 or wow64 folder? if it has been installed you need to ensure that c:\windows\system32 comes before the ms symbol server see this [excerpt](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5VAmuo5Rn94C&pg=PT436&lpg=PT436&dq=vfbasics.pdb&source=bl&ots=ChjlBPmzz9&sig=IEfVVFIGy5I27RHpZPzPnAO0zDU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nKXAUL-5NYjj4QSFs4HQAQ&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBg)

Comment: Nope, no pdb in site. I checked these places, that's why I posted the question in the first place. Do you have the pdb in Windows 7?

Comment: No it is not on my system, the point being it is installed by ApplicationVerifier and therefore it has private symbols which is why it is not located at the MS symbol store, install app verifier [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20028) and then add the path to c:\windows\system32 ensuring it appears before the MS symbol store in your symbol path and it should resolve it fine, if this works for you I will post this as an answer

Comment: I have it installed as part of the windows SDK, along with the debugging and performance tools. No pdb in site.

Comment: I just installed app verifier from this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20028 and it popped up in C:\windows\system32, I installed the 64 bit version. Maybe try reinstalling from this link

Comment: Hmm, strange. Arrange your comment as the answer and I will credit you for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vfbasics.pdb is installed as part of Application Verifier and uses private symbols, this is why the public MS symbol store server does not have this pdb.

It looks like from our comments that there has been some error in the installation, you can reinstall Application Verifier from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20028), I just installed the 64 bit version and it appeared in

> c:\windows\system32

Another thing to note from the book [Inside Windows Debugging](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5VAmuo5Rn94C&pg=PT436&lpg=PT436&dq=vfbasics.pdb&source=bl&ots=ChjlBPmzz9&sig=IEfVVFIGy5I27RHpZPzPnAO0zDU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nKXAUL-5NYjj4QSFs4HQAQ&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBg) is that you must put `c:\windows\system32` *before* the MS public symbol server path.

Comment: @jheriko this answer was correct when I answered it, you've not stated why you feel it is now incorrect or unhelpful. Also even if this answer is completely wrong, which is may well be seeing as I answered it nearly 3 years ago I can't delete it as it's been accepted by the OP so you need to indicate to the OP that this answer is wrong also

Comment: the link from there doesn't produce the file in the location specified. thats all... i'm sure its not worth changing, but its still not useful anymore. maybe this is something stack overflow needs to improve with?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the PDB is missing the MSI's. It used to be in MSI's for the earlier versions back to 4.1. But since going to 6.2 (part of Windows 7\8 SDK), the MSI's to not have the private PDBs.

Still looking...

FILE TABLE from Application Verifier x64 External Package-x64_en-us.msi

```
vfluapriv.dll                                 281656    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    35
vfluapriv.dll                                 242776    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    25
catdc3acb184552e9eeac50269425274d3c.cat       9783                                512    29
vfprintpthelper.dll                           711320    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    36
appverif.chm                                  657331                              512    15
appverif.chm                                  657331                              512    6
appverif.exe                                  173520    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    9
appverif.exe                                  216816    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    17
cuzzapi.dll                                   23072     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    34
cuzzapi.dll                                   21448     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    22
cat2d609858545493b503b24bd3328d8d2a.cat       8157                                512    5
cat4c0b3f635c0903217a3535759b7ce85f.cat       7792                                512    10
catb1033a9482d5307d3df8fcd97174719e.cat       9783                                512    19
vfprintpthelper.dll                           367392    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    26
cat9070517e54c750dca5f4eaa025eb8057.cat       8136                                512    14
vfntlmless.dll                                40136     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    27
vfntlmless.dll                                45336     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    37
vfbasics.dll                                  406848    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    16
vfbasics.dll                                  353328    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    8
vfcompat.dll                                  90480     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    38
vfcompat.dll                                  87328     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    21
vfcuzz.dll                                    48976     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    30
vfcuzz.dll                                    52032     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    23
vfnet.dll                                     105056    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    33
vfnet.dll                                     81592     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    20
vfnws.dll                                     83248     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    31
vfnws.dll                                     61384     6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    24
vfprint.dll                                   433376    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    32
vfprint.dll                                   306592    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    28
vrfauto.dll                                   211064    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    2
vrfauto.dll                                   167392    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    12
vrfauto.h                                     112394                              512    4
vrfauto.h                                     112394                              512    13
vrfauto.idl                                   31344                               512    3
vrfauto.idl                                   31344                               512    11
vrfcore.dll                                   183568    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    18
vrfcore.dll                                   164200    6.2.9200.16384    1033    512    7
cat0f5c9874ec8b03b3a2ef2148f76b34cf.cat       7792                                512    1
```